# JavaScript error on main site

Tags: bug, firefox

I've been consistently getting the following JavaScript error on Stack Overflow while using Firefox on different computers:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
>   wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/.
>   https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=0852174734c9 Line 1

I've tried the usual troubleshooting: update Firefox, clear caches and [check meta for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135062/firefox-cant-establish-a-connection-to-the-server-at-ws-sockets-ny-stackexcha). The fact it is happening across different instances of Firefox but works fine on other browsers makes me think it is a Firefox specific error. I've received the error on Firefox 48, 49, 50b3.

Has anyone else been getting this error or know of a solution to it?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox 49.0.1 on Windows 8.1...

Comment: Are you running any custom extensions enabled? Have you tried running Stack Overflow without *any* extensions enabled?

Comment: @MikeC good call, looks like it was related to the HTTPS Everywhere add-on causing the block.

Comment: Do you have some proxy or any service which may cause requests blocking behind you?

Comment: Same thing on main Meta [“HTTPS Everywhere” browser add-on breaks site updates (websocket?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284855/https-everywhere-browser-add-on-breaks-site-updates-websocket/)

Answer (score 5):

The HTTPS Everywhere add-on is causing the issue, so this could extend to other users using the add-on on different browsers. Disabling it for Stack Overflow fixes the issue.